# Excel Addin not executing Call Function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

I have a sharepoint site which I use vba to upload new data. I have created a Excel Addin which we will deploy to other users so that anybody can upload.

The Excel Addin consists of two modules. The first module is the "functions" module and the second is the code which runs when the button is pushed on the Addin. If I test all this with a normal Excel Macro workbook, it works perfect. However when I test it in the Addin feature, the "Call SaveChanges" part does not work.

Does anybody have any idea what is causing this part to not work? I have even tried adding another button on the Addin for the SaveChanges part but still not working as a Addin.

The SaveChanges Sub it is calling is what saves the data back to sharepoint.

Module 1

```
Option Explicit
Sub link_edit_Mode()
    
    Dim mySh As Worksheet
    Dim spSite As String
    
    Set mySh = Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim src(0 To 1) As Variant
    
    spSite = "https://share.websitehere.com/sites/sitename/" 'site name
    src(0) = spSite & "/_vti_bin"
    
    src(1) = "{00000000-8F5B-4736-B48F-337D350E18C1}" 'GUID
    
    mySh.ListObjects.Add xlSrcExternal, src, True, xlYes, mySh.Range("A1")
    
End Sub

Sub SaveChanges()

   Dim mySh As Worksheet
   Dim lstOBJ As ListObject

   On Error GoTo errhdnler
   
   Set mySh = Sheets("Sheet1")
   Set lstOBJ = mySh.ListObjects(1)
   
   lstOBJ.UpdateChanges xlListConflictDialog
   
   Set mySh = Nothing
   Set lstOBJ = Nothing
   
Exit Sub
errhdnler:

Debug.Print Err.Description & Err.Number

End Sub

Sub refresh_Con()

   Dim mySh As Worksheet
   Dim lstOBJ As ListObject

On Error GoTo errhdnler

   Set mySh = Sheets("Sheet1")
   
   Set lstOBJ = mySh.ListObjects(1)
   
   lstOBJ.Refresh
  
   Set mySh = Nothing
   Set lstOBJ = Nothing
   
Exit Sub

errhdnler:

Debug.Print Err.Description & Err.Number

End Sub
```

Module 2

```
Sub FollowUps(control As IRibbonControl)
'
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long
Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet

Rows("1:5").Select
Range("A5").Activate
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Columns("H:H").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("I:I").EntireColumn.AutoFit

Sheets.Add.Name = "Sheet1"

' Worksheets("Sheet1").Visible = True

Call link_edit_Mode

Do While (Selection.Offset(1, 0) <> "")
   Range("A3").Select
   Selection.ListObject.ListRows(1).Delete
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
Range("A2").Select

Loop

'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
Set wsCopy = Workbooks("SA_Follow_Ups.xlsx").Worksheets("Follow Ups OpenUnresolved Over")
Set wsDest = Workbooks("SA_Follow_Ups.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")

'1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column A
lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'2. Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column A
'Offset property moves down 1 row
lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0).Row

'3. Copy & Paste Data
wsCopy.Range("A2:I" & lCopyLastRow).copy
wsDest.Range("B" & lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial xlValues

Call SaveChanges

ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out.

```
Sub SaveChanges()

   Dim mySh As Worksheet
   Dim objListObj As ListObject

   On Error GoTo errhdnler
   
   Set mySh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
   Set objListObj = mySh.ListObjects("Table1")
   
   objListObj.UpdateChanges xlListConflictDialog
   
   Set mySh = Nothing
   Set objListObj = Nothing
   
Exit Sub
errhdnler:

Debug.Print Err.Description & Err.Number

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the code as an Add-In, you need to specify that you no longer want to save something in a sheet of the Add-In itself, but rather a sheet of the ActiveWorkbook.

So you need to add a couple of lines:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Set mySh= wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

Comment: I have tried that and its still not working?

Comment: Have you implemented this in all functions where it's necessary?

Comment: thank you so much, I did yes, i changed it in the module holding the functions but does not work.

Comment: And does it give any error in the debug window? Since that is part of the code of SaveChanges

Comment: No error at all, I even tried to not hide the sheet which comes after the savechanges call but that didnt work. Strange it works perfect as a workbook but its just as a Addon its giving this issue.

Comment: And the rest of the code works? The part before SaveChanges?

Comment: Correct yes everything else works. Its just the Save part that does not